# Thread Building Blocks flow graph — limiter_node-like thing that does not drop messages

Tags: c++, multithreading, tbb

Is it possible to have something like a `limiter_node<T>` which protects a queue from overflowing, but instead of discarding messages which do not fit into the queue forwards them to some other node?  I want to have something like

```
typedef std::string S;
using namespace tbb::flow;
source_node<S> input(g, Input(), false);
limiter_node<S> limiter(g, queue_len);
function_node<S, S> processor(g, threadpool_size, Processor());
function_node<S, int> output(g, serial, Output());

make_edge(input, limiter);
make_edge(limiter, processor);
make_edge(limiter.magic_forwarder_of_failed_deliveries_thank_you, output); // ???
make_edge(processor, output);
make_edge(output, limiter.decrement);
```

Basically I want to process as much data as possible with a ton of blocking IO-bound «nodes» and forward the rest straight to the output node unprocessed.

Comment: It seems [multifunction_node](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/tbb_sa/help/reference/flow_graph/multifunc_node_cls.htm) is suitable for "selector" node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Disclosure: I work on Intel Threading Building Blocks at Intel.)

I agree with yohjp, you could do this with a multifunction_node.

```
typedef multifunction_node< S, tuple< S, S > > mnode_t;

struct Forwarder {
// This assumes
//   port 0 is connected to the limiter
//   port 1 is the alternative path
void operator()( const S &s, mnode_t::output_ports_type &outs ) {
    if ( !get<0>(outs).try_put(s) ) {
        get<1>(outs).try_put(s);
    }
} };
```

With edges changed so that:

```
make_edge(input, forwarder);
make_edge(output_port<0>(forwarder), limiter);
make_edge(limiter, processor);
make_edge(output_port<1>(forwarder), output);
```

You'd also have to work out a way that the decrement is called only for those things that went through the processor.

Comment: Does try_put return false when it fails to send a datum into a full limiter node, or does the limiter node drop the item silently?

Comment: The try_put will return false. But looks like you've already verified that.  Glad I could be of help.